# Set default to return if undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible in JS to return nothing for a function using the set default syntax. i.e exit out of the function if the value is undefined.

Something like this:

```
const x = section.x || return
```

I suspect not seeing as the idea is to set a value. If this is the case, is there any clean, concise one liner alternatives to achieve this.

Comment: better will be not to call the function if the value is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not elegantly. `return` is a statement; it must exist *standalone*, not connected to any previous expressions. `|| return` isn't valid for the same reason `|| if (condition) {` isn't valid. You'll need to put the `return` on its own line:

```
const { x } = section;
if (!x) return;
```

Another option (highly not recommended, but just FYI) would be to throw inside an IIFE and catch in the caller:

```js
const fn = () => {
  const section = {};
  const x = section.x || (() => { throw new Error(); })();
};

try {
  fn();
} catch(e) {
}
console.log('fn done');
```

(if/once [throw expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-throw-expressions) become a thing, the above can be simplified a *bit*: `section.x || throw new Error();`)